# how to access to json fields with webix and get data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, webix

I'm beginner with webix, Just started to link with mongodb.
Now, I started loading my data from my DB.
But when it comes to deal with Objects, I can't get the data.

```
 webix.ready(function () {
    var grida = webix.ui({
      container: "testA",
      id: "pivot", url: "/rent", save: "rest->/rent",
      view: "pivot",
      height: 400,
      width: 1000,

      max: true,
      structure: {
        rows: ["from"],
        columns: ["created"],
      }

    });

  });
```

and this is my json field that I copied from my mongoDB.

```
 "from" : {
        "agency" : ObjectId("554"), 
        "place" : ObjectId("554dc4"), 
        "date" : ISODate("2014-08-09T06:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "completed" : false
    },
```

First, how to access to the data inside the object?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please provide a webix snippet to demonstrate your problem

Comment: http://webix.com/snippet/de365cf2

Answer (score 0):

You can use "scheme" to preprocess data before loading it in the pivot

```
webix.ui({
  id: "pivot",
  scheme:{
    $init:function(obj){
      obj.phone = obj.phones? obj.phones[0].number : "Empty"
    }
   }
```